# Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]

Tags: spring, jpa

I have the following code:

```
    package com.transcend.txn;

    public class JpaTxnMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JpaAccountDao.addAccount();
        }
    }

    package com.transcend.txn;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    @Repository("spitterDao")
    @Transactional
    public class JpaAccountDao {

        static{
            initContext();
        }

        @PersistenceContext
        private static EntityManager em;

        public static void addAccount() {
            Account account = new Account();
            account.setId("100");
            em.persist(account);
        }

        public static void initContext() {
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("main-annotation.xml");
        }

    }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
     xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

        <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.transcend.txn" /> 
            <property name="dataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="mySqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:qadb7"/>
            <property name="username" value="tp2"/>
            <property name="password" value="tp2"/>
            <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

When i try to execute the above code i get the following error:

```
        log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.transcend.txn.JpaTxnMain.main(JpaTxnMain.java:6)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [main-annotation.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in class path resource [main-annotation.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaVendorAdapter' while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [main-annotation.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:741)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.transcend.txn.JpaAccountDao.initContext(JpaAccountDao.java:30)
        at com.transcend.txn.JpaAccountDao.<clinit>(JpaAccountDao.java:17)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in class path resource [main-annotation.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaVendorAdapter' while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [main-annotation.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:438)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:71)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1470)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        ... 12 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [main-annotation.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1000)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 46 more
```

I have following jars:

```
    aopalliance-1.0.jar 
    commons-dbcp-1.4.jar 
    commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 
    commons-pool-1.5.4.jar 
    ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar 
    log4j-1.2.17.jar 
    persistence-api-1.0.2.jar 
    spring-aop-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar 
    spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar 
    spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar 
    spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar 
    spring-expression-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar 
    spring-jdbc-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar 
    spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar 
    spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
```

I have excluded persistence-api-1.0.2.jar from class path. I have spent lot of time trying to resolve the problem. Can some one please help to resolve the problem.

Comment: You want to use hibernate but forgot to include the hibernate dependencies, you only have the spring wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is you need hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager for HIbernate support.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not the necessary libraries! 
I prefer you to use a library dependency manager like Maven.
Maven handles dependency between libraries and you will not worry about it anymore.